# Unable to pick the inner tag value of xml by parsing in android

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing, domparser

I am working on to parse this xml's inner tag's value but didn't succeed. I have used the DOM parser and SAX parser.

```
<XML>
       <VersionStatus>0</VersionStatus>
       <VersionUrl>NA</VersionUrl>  
       <photo>http://demo.stellans.com/posterduck/images/Android_Images/</photo>
       <size>
         <options>4X11</options><options>8X11</options>
       </size>
       <category>
         <options>sticker</options>
         <options>card</options>
       </category>
       <Noofprints>
         <options>1</options>
         <options>2</options>
         <options>3</options>
         <options>4</options>
         <options>5</options>
         <options>6</options>
      </Noofprints>
      <selectaddress/>
    </XML>
```

and here is , [My Main Activity](http://pastie.org/private/xq0domdezcld93sszqhfq) 
and  [My Connection Class to parse xml](http://pastie.org/private/pra5jvcb21revfj9rodtw)

Guide me where i am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to be answerable as-is, not requiring external links.